# how to get value in javascript from three differents select

Tags: javascript, function, select

i try to calcul age automaticly when user select his date of birth with three different dropdown list
i need for my function to get these three values from the three differents select.
I can make this with only one select but i can't find the good solution with many select.
I need 3 values for the last ligne (x, y, z)
Tell me what is the problem with my javascript code please.

happy new year for everybody!

```
$(document).ready(function calage() {

var year = document.getElementById("year" );
 var x = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
var month = document.getElementById("month" );
 var y = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
var day = document.getElementById("day" );
var z = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;


var calculate_age = (function (){
"use strict";

return function(date_start){
var date_end = new Date(), date_end_time = date_end.getTime(),      date_start_time = date_start.getTime(), diff = (date_end_time-date_start_time)/(1000*60*60*24);
 return Math.floor(diff/365+1);
 };

 })();

 document.getElementById('age').value=(calculate_age(new Date(x, y,z)));
 });
```

And this is my html with input and select dropdown (simplified)

```
   <input id="age" name="age" type="text" disabled="disabled"  style="float: right;">

  <select name="day" id="day">
      <option value="empty" disabled selected>le</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
     </select>


  <select name="month" id="month">
      <option value="empty" disabled selected>le</option>
      <option value="jan">january</option>
      <option value="feb">2febrary</option>
      <option value="mar">march</option>
      <option value="apr">april</option>
     </select>


  <select onchange="calage() name="year" id="year">
      <option value="empty" disabled selected>le</option>
      <option value="1950">1950</option>
      <option value="1951">1951</option>
      <option value="1952">1952</option>
      <option value="1953">1953</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: You’re setting the variables `x`, `y` and `z` to the same value, which is - probably - either `null`or a syntax error is being thrown given that you’ve never declared the `select` variable.

Comment: Yes exact but i didn't know how to declare different select. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. I hope it makes sense.  Some of the changes were cosmetic.  The main change is that instead of `select.options...` I replaced `select` with `year`, `month`, and `day` for their respective lines. See below snippet.

```
var calculate_age = function(date_start){
    var date_end = new Date(), date_end_time = date_end.getTime();
    var date_start_time = date_start.getTime();
    var diff = (date_end_time - date_start_time)/(1000*60*60*24);
    return Math.floor(diff/365+1);
};

function calage() {
    console.log('in calage')
    var year = document.getElementById("year" );
    var x = year.options[year.selectedIndex].value;
    var month = document.getElementById("month" );
    var y = month.options[month.selectedIndex].value;
    var day = document.getElementById("day" );
    var z = day.options[day.selectedIndex].value;

    if (x !== 'empty' && y !== 'empty' && z !== 'empty') {
        console.log('x: ', x);
        console.log('y: ', y);
        console.log('z: ', z);
        document.getElementById('age').value=(calculate_age(new Date(x, y, z)));
    }
}

$(document).ready(calage);
```

The other significant change is that the value for the months needed to be changed to numbers instead of the short names.  So `0, 1, 2...` instead of `jan, feb, mar` because the `new Date()` constructor expects numbers.

So to sum it up, as `David Thomas` mentioned above you were using the undeclared variable `select` repeatedly for each of the values set by the `select` components.  You weren't even using the values that you were setting in `year`, `month`, and `day`

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Maninacan/pen/QzOJxy) for the working example.

Comment: Thank you very much! very good explanation. moreover with example in codepen. Code works fine and i understood how to make that now

Comment: Anyway do you know why i have a offset when the birthday is near of the actual date?  (something about 12 days) for example my birthday is 24/12/1973 (45y.o) but the code return 44 y.o - it returns only 45 when i put 11/12/1973

Comment: @mantraaxx I'd have to see how you are using those dates in the code to know for sure, but some things to consider: the format for creating a date is `new Date(<year>, <month>, <day of the month>)` keeping in mind that month starts with `0` and goes to `11`.  For example, `new Date(1973, 24, 12)` assuming `24/12/1973` is formatted as `<day>/<month>/<year>`.  If this answered your question I would appreciate it if you marked this answer as the best solution. ;-)

Comment: Ok thanks for explanation - Sorry to forgot to mark the aswer as best solution - Now is Ok

Answer (score 0):

```
    calage = ()=>{
        let x = getValue("day");
        let y = getValue("month");
        let z = getValue("year");

        console.log(`${x} , ${y}, ${z}`);
    }

    getValue = (targetName)=>{
        return document.getElementById(targetName).value;
    }
```

You also did not close your "" on the 'onchange' property.

Comment: oh yes i forgot to close the onchange Thanks!